# Issues while calling nltk libraries using jython

Tags: java, python, nlp, nltk, jython

I am trying to call nltk libraries which are integrated in my python code. As per requirement I need to call them through my java code, therefore, I am using Jython for the integration.
If my pyhton code does not includes any nltk library, in such case it works fine. But when it includes nltk library, it gives me import error. 
I have already added nltk related system paths to the interpreter

```
PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
sys.path.append(new PyString("c:\\Python27\\Lib"));
sys.path.append(new PyString("c:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages"));
sys.path.append(new PyString("C:\\Python27\\DLLs"));
sys.path.append(new PyString("C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk"));
sys.path.append(new PyString("C:\\Python27"));
sys.path.append(new PyString("C:\\Python27\\libs"));
```

I am getting the follwoing error while executing my java code

```
console: Failed to install '': java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0.
Exception in thread "MainThread" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenextractor.py", line 7, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import *
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\snowball.py", line 26, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

_sqlite3 is available under Python27/libs, When I executes the python program as a standalone script, it works fine, but while running with Java it gives me this error.

Comment: If you need NLP for Java, why not try Stanford NLP?  https://nlp.stanford.edu/  Looks like Python NLTK requires a SQLite module as a dependency.

Comment: I need to use some more features from nltk, and some addtional libraries written in python. For this it is must for me to have a wrapper responsible for this communication between java and python

Comment: Jython is Python 2.7; that's not a good thing in the age of Python 3.x as production. I'm suggesting that you might consider finding Java equivalents to those Python libraries.  I'm confident that the Java ecosystem is at least as extensive is Python's.  If you really need and know Python, what is Java buying you?

Comment: Do you really have to use Python 2.7? The nltk moved to Python 3 long ago, the Python 3 is by now the more stable one. I'd try that first. Anyway unless you actually use a library that needs it, you could try hacking the nltk code to suppress import of the problem packages. `sqlite3` is only mentioned in `panlex_lite.py`, `chat80.py`, and `relextract.py`.