# Unable to import python module in JYTHON using java

Tags: java, python, nltk, jython

I have a java code in which I am executing python file using jython. I works well for default python dependencies but not work when I give some addition python modules. Python code is working fine in python console.

java code

```
PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
sys.path.append(new PyString("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"));
sys.path.append(new PyString("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"));

PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), arguments);
PythonInterpreter python = new PythonInterpreter(null, sys);
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
python.setOut(out);
python.execfile("/home/lucy/input.py");
```

input.py

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

error

```
  import nltk
SyntaxError: ("mismatched input 'as' expecting COLON", ('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py', 35, 15, 'except IOError as ex:\n'))
```

sys version

> '2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) \n[GCC 4.8.4]'

jython version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the 'as' was a comma in python 2.5, sure you are using python 2.7?

Comment: What version of the Python language is your JYTHON?

Comment: You can see what version you have by displaying the value of `sys.version` (after an `import sys`).

Comment: updated question

Comment: It seems hard (impossible?) to use NLTK in Jython. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45280461/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46163994/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46968333/407651

Comment: for textblob -> SyntaxError: ('future feature unicode_literals is not defined', ('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/blob.py', 23, 0, ''))

Comment: @lucy If you pass `new PySystemState()` then that would reset the sys path you have set

Comment: @htopiwala updated the code but still have same issue